# Tkinter Canvas create_window()

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to use `Tkinter Canvas` (`self._canvas`) to create window using `create_window` function. The **window** field for that function is a `Tkinter Frame` (`self._tableFrame`). Can someone please help me out on how to make `self._tableFrame` to expand to size of `self._canvas` automatically (Even after the window size changed by user)?

**Code:**

```
from Tkinter import Scrollbar as tkScrollBar
from Tkinter import Frame as tkFrame
from Tkinter import Canvas as tkCanvas
from Tkinter import Entry as tkEntry
from Tkinter import StringVar as tkStringVar
from Tkinter import Tk, HORIZONTAL, N, S, E, W, RIGHT, LEFT, BOTTOM, X, Y, BOTH
from Tkinter import TOP


class Widget(tkFrame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tkFrame.__init__(self, master)

        self._str    = tkStringVar()
        self._widget = tkEntry(self)

        self._widget.config(textvariable=self._str, borderwidth=1, width=0)
        self._widget.pack(expand=True, fill=X)

    def settext(self, str_):
        self._str.set(str_)

    def gettext(self):
        return self._str.get()


class Application(tkFrame):
    def __init__(self, rows, cols, master=None):
        tkFrame.__init__(self, master)

        yScroll = tkScrollBar(self)
        xScroll = tkScrollBar(self, orient=HORIZONTAL)

        self._canvas = tkCanvas(self,
                yscrollcommand=yScroll.set, xscrollcommand=xScroll.set)
        yScroll.config(command=self._canvas.yview)
        xScroll.config(command=self._canvas.xview)

        self._table      = [[0 for x in range(rows)] for x in range(cols)]
        self._tableFrame = tkFrame(self._canvas)

        for col in range(cols):
            self._tableFrame.grid_columnconfigure(col, weight=1)
            for row in range(rows):
                self._table[row][col] = Widget(master=self._tableFrame)
                self._table[row][col].settext("(%d, %d)" % (row, col))
                self._table[row][col].grid(row=row, column=col, sticky=E+W)

        # For debugging
        self._canvas.config(background="blue")
        self._tableFrame.config(background="red")

        yScroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        xScroll.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

        self._canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=self._tableFrame, anchor=N+W)
        self._canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)


tkRoot  = Tk()

# Application Size and Center the Application
appSize = (800, 600)
w       = tkRoot.winfo_screenwidth()
h       = tkRoot.winfo_screenheight()

x = w / 2 - appSize[0] / 2
y = h / 2 - appSize[1] / 2
tkRoot.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (appSize + (x, y)))
tkRoot.update_idletasks() # Force geometry update

app = Application(5, 5, master=tkRoot)
app.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
tkRoot.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can bind `self._canvas` with the event `<Configure>`, and then call `itemconfig` with the id of the frame added to the canvas (not directly the reference to the widget):

```
def __init__(self, rows, cols, master=None):
    # ...
    self._frame_id = self._canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=self._tableFrame, anchor=N+W)
    self._canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
    self._canvas.bind("<Configure>", self.resize_frame)

def resize_frame(self, e):
    self._canvas.itemconfig(self._frame_id, height=e.height, width=e.width)
```

By the way, I recommend you to rewrite your `import` statements, which in my opinion are quite repetitive and *unpythonic*:

```
import tkinter as tk
# Use tk.Tk, tk.Canvas, etc.
```