# Python Tkinter - How to move a textbox by pixels

Tags: python, text, textbox, tkinter, move

What the title says.
I'm having a problem moving the textbox from a side to side.
The code's long and it's about 200+ lines so I wont post it here.
Anybody has an idea?

Comment: Could you extract a small working peace of code to give us an example?

Comment: how can we possibly know what you're doing wrong without seeing your code? You don't have to post all 200+ lines -- reduce it down to the smallest number of lines that still i llustrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have various options for this, depending on what you mean by "text box," and whether you want to move it "by pixels" or "from a side to [another] side."

If you just want to display text, you can use a `Label` widget. If you want a text box where the user can enter text, try an `Entry` widget. If you want to move your widget from one area of the screen to another, you can use the `grid` geometry manager and simply use `grid_forget` to "unplace" your widget then `grid` (with different options than you originally used, of course) to put it somewhere else.

If you just have text and you'd like to move it pixel by pixel, you could create a `Canvas` and then use that widget's `create_text` method to create some text in a specific place on the `Canvas`. You can the use the `Canvas` widget's `itemconfig` method to move the text to a new location.

If you need something more complex than text, like an `Entry` widget, and you want to move it pixel by pixel, do the same as above but use the `create_window` method instead.

See [`Canvas`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm), [`grid`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm), [`Label`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm), [`Entry`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm), and [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980812/how-do-you-create-a-button-on-a-tkinter-canvas) SO [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16820520/tkinter-canvas-create-window) about `create_window`.